# Dash JS Player Cross Browser Compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, streaming

I am conducting a research for my company streaming service. I found `dash.js` for adaptive streaming which is a perfect solution along with ffMpeg for transcoding.

So how this solution works is to create bunch of files served in .mpd format. Now the questions I have:

1. Do you think this a early stage and I should wait before start using DASH.JS? Do you think there is a better solution for safe and fast streaming?
2. Player options: So far the only player I found was this http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.0.0/

   I have no idea how compatible it is with browsers and what limits I'll be facing if I chose it. Is there any other solid solution for this?
3. Do you guys think I'm going wrong direction for this?
4. What are my server requirements to run these technologies? I have a 500MBs, 64GB Ram, 24 Core, 2TB beast, does this do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Many companies are already using dash as their media delivery. I don't think it's too early to start.

2) There are numerous streaming solutions for Dash. A lot of which are listed here http://dashif.org/clients/

3) Personally, no. It's the path the standard is heading IMO(just from my research and hands on in the field)

4) I can't comment as we don't do our own encoding or transcoding.

Hope this helps. There's a ton of information on http://dashif.org/